# jQuery ajax response not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to create a loginpage with jQuery/AJAX, my code work well in other browser but i  have a problem in IE11. 
 IE11 throw an exception

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x800c0008, The download of the    specified resource has failed.
```

Code

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: $('#form-login').attr('action'),
        data: $('#form-login').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            if (isJson(data)) {
                ...
            }
        },
        complete: function (data) {
            console.log(data);

            if (data.status == 302) {
                location.href = data.responseText;
            }
        }
    });`
```

Comment: The is no file it's just response with redirection. it's 0.4k large response.

Comment: You have a network issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem that the problem is only with 302 (redirect Response), i changed it to 203 and all work fine.